# Insert into JSON objects postgres using Node without forloop for every db.query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sql-insert, postgis

I have an array of objects like with the same setup as the one below. I wanna insert this array of objects into postgres table that looks like this:[![Table setup][1]][1]
I have tried to make a function below but it returns error when inserting UNGDOMSKOLE because this is a string so it doesn't understand the space so it crashes on the second input value. How can I make it understand it is a string?

```
{
  '@type': 'SensorSystem',
  id: 'SN47230',
  name: 'ÅKRA UNGDOMSSKOLE',
  shortName: 'Åkra ',
  country: 'Norge',
  countryCode: 'NO',
  geometry: {
    '@type': 'Point',
    coordinates: [ 5.1963, 59.2555 ],
    nearest: false
  },
  masl: 18,
  validFrom: '2013-10-29T00:00:00.000Z',
  county: 'ROGALAND',
  countyId: 11,
  municipality: 'KARMØY',
  municipalityId: 1149,
  stationHolders: [ 'KARMØY KOMMUNE' ],
  externalIds: [ '506131077' ],
  wigosId: '0-578-0-47230'
}
```

Error code:

```
error: syntax error at or near "UNGDOMSSKOLE"
```

What I have tried so far:

```
let sqlinsert= data.data.map((source)=>{
          if (source.geometry) {
            if(!source.masl){
              source.masl=0
          }
          let Point = `POINT(${source.geometry.coordinates[0]} ${source.geometry.coordinates[1]})`;
          return `(${source.id}, ${source.name}, ${source.shortName},${source.country},${source.countryCode},${source.masl},${source.geometry.coordinates[0]},${source.geometry.coordinates[1]},${Point},${source.validFrom},${source.county},${source.countyId},${source.municipality},${source.municipalityId})`
          }
        })
const result = await db.query("INSERT INTO sources(source_id,name,shortName,country,countryCode,masl,long,lat,geog,valid_from,county,countyId,municipality,municipalityId) values"+sqlinsert[0])
```

A second problem I have with this is that inserting

```
POINT(59.2555 5.1963)
```

Gives a syntax error at 5.1963
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RSkq.png

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your query as written is that you are adding raw, unescaped values into your VALUES records. You can use `escapeLiteral` on your db client to ensure that these values are properly escaped which will solve the syntax errors you are getting:

```js
    const data = [
      {
        "@type": "SensorSystem",
        id: "SN47230",
        name: "ÅKRA UNGDOMSSKOLE",
        shortName: "Åkra ",
        country: "Norge",
        countryCode: "NO",
        geometry: {
          "@type": "Point",
          coordinates: [5.1963, 59.2555],
          nearest: false,
        },
        masl: 18,
        validFrom: "2013-10-29T00:00:00.000Z",
        county: "ROGALAND",
        countyId: 11,
        municipality: "KARMØY",
        municipalityId: 1149,
        stationHolders: ["KARMØY KOMMUNE"],
        externalIds: ["506131077"],
        wigosId: "0-578-0-47230",
      },
    ].map((source) => {
      const {
        id,
        name,
        shortName,
        country,
        countryCode,
        masl,
        geometry: {
          // the coordinates in your source data appear to be in y,x instead of
          // x,y. Treating them as x,y results in the point being located
          // in the Indian Ocean while y,x is somewhere in Norway.
          coordinates: [lat, long],
        },
        validFrom,
        county,
        countyId,
        municipality,
        municipalityId,
      } = source;

      return [
        id,
        name,
        shortName,
        country,
        countryCode,
        masl || 0,
        long,
        lat,
        `POINT( ${long} ${lat} )`,
        validFrom,
        county,
        countyId,
        municipality,
        municipalityId,
      ];
    });

    const headers = [
      "source_id",
      "name",
      "shortname",
      "country",
      "countrycode",
      "masl",
      "long",
      "lat",
      "geog",
      "valid_from",
      "county",
      "countyid",
      "municipality",
      "municipalityid",
    ];

    const sourceValStr = data
      .map((sourceRecords, rowIndex) => {
        return sourceRecords
          .map((value, colIndex) => {
            if (typeof value === "string") {
              // safely escape string values
              return dbClient.escapeLiteral(value);
            }
            if (
              typeof value === "number" ||
              typeof value === "boolean" ||
              typeof value === "bigint"
            ) {
              return value;
            }

            if (value === undefined || value === null) {
              return "null";
            }

            throw new Error(
              `non-simple value: ${JSON.stringify(value)} for ${
                headers[colIndex]
              } at row ${rowIndex}`
            );
          })
          .join(",");
      })
      .map((value) => `(${value})`)
      .join(",");

    const sourceInsert = `INSERT INTO sources(${headers.join(
      ","
    )}) VALUES ${sourceValStr};`;
    await dbClient.query(sourceInsert);
```

A much more efficient and scalable way to insert the rows is to use the [pg-copy-streams](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-copy-streams) library in conjunction with a CSV library like [csv-stringify](https://csv.js.org/stringify/examples/) which will bulk insert using a [`COPY FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) stream:

```js
import { from as copyFrom } from "pg-copy-streams";
import { stringify } from "csv-stringify";
// ...
const copyStmt = `COPY sources(${headers.join(
      ","
    )}) FROM STDIN (FORMAT CSV)`;
await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      const copyStream = dbClient.query(copyFrom(copyStmt));
      const stringifiedStream = stringify(data, {
        header: false,
        encoding: "utf-8",
        delimiter: ",",
        quote: "\"",
      });
      stringifiedStream
        .on("error", (err) => {
          reject(err);
        })
        .on("end", () => resolve());
      stringifiedStream.pipe(copyStream);
    });
```

On my low-end laptop, this approach takes about 39 seconds to insert a million rows with no database optimizations.

Comment: I was doing what I was doing to avoid making over 100k different db.queries and instead do one. But if I follow your way will I then end up having one query to the database for each object or just once?

Comment: @matieva  I updated my answer to avoid the need to issue a query call per row.